# Is there an object which groups two vectors together?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Is there a single name for a pair of vectors that together describe a position and orientation? Like an "oriented point" or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the idea of a tangent vector from differential geometry, where each point $p$ in a space $M$ has a full vector space $T_p M$ of tangent vectors "based at" that point.

In particular you're talking about a tangent vector to an affine space - that is, a vector $v \in T_p \mathbb R^n \simeq \mathbb R^n$ based at a point $p \in \mathbb R^n$. The pair $(p,v)$ is then a *tangent vector to $\mathbb R^n$*, or an element of the *tangent bundle* $T\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: To clarify, suppose I had a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $p$ be the north pole of that sphere. Then would the tangent bundle to that sphere at $p$ be a 2D plane? (And does it make sense to phrase it this way)?

Comment: @evenex_code: the tangent *space* to the sphere at the point would be a 2D plane. The tangent bundle is what you get when you "bundle up" *all* of the tangent spaces into a single object - it is the set of all pairs $(p,v)$ where $p$ is a point in the space and $v$ is a tangent vector based at that point.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of a point and a vector is called a "ray" or an "axis" in some disciplines.

A combination of a point and an orientation (where orientation = rotation matrix) is called a "frame" sometimes.

I don't think these terms are well accepted in any branches of pure mathematics. I have heard them in computer science and engineering, mostly.